# Excel VBA that brings in weather shapes - Trying to delete shapes before rerun

Tags: excel, shapes, weather, vba

I am currently using this code to pull out the 5-day forecast along with some decent pictures for an assignment. I had built it off of a video I found but I'm having trouble with why the delshape process isn't removing the shapes as it should.

If anyone has any recommendations I would appreciate it as well as trying to explain what is wrong if possible. I am trying to learn as much as I can with VBA as I am a brand new user.

```
Sub CurrentFiveDayForecast()


Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveSheet

>WS.Range("thedate").Value = ""
WS.Range("hightemp").Value = ""
WS.Range("lowtemp").Value = ""

Dim delshape As Shape
For Each delshape In WS.Shapes
If delshape.Type = msoAutoShape Then delshape.Delete

Next delshape



Dim Req As New XMLHTTP
Req.Open "GET", "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Hong+Kong&format=xml&num_of_days=5&key=APIKEY", False

Req.send

Dim Resp As New DomDocument
Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText
Dim Weather As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Integer
Dim wShape As Shape
Dim thiscell As Range


For Each Weather In Resp.getElementsByTagName("weather")
i = i + 1

WS.Range("thedate").Cells(1, i).Value = Weather.SelectNodes("date")(0).Text
WS.Range("hightemp").Cells(1, i).Value = Weather.SelectNodes("tempMaxF")(0).Text
WS.Range("lowtemp").Cells(1, i).Value = Weather.SelectNodes("tempMinF")(0).Text
Set thiscell = WS.Range("weatherpictures").Cells(1, i)
Set wShape = WS.Shapes.AddPicture(Weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl")(0).Text, msoFalse, msoCTrue, thiscell.Left, thiscell.Top, thiscell.Width, thiscell.Height)



Next Weather

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shapes.AddPicture` Creates a picture from an existing file. It returns a Shape object that represents the new picture. You can read more about it in [Shapes.AddPicture Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198302.aspx)

Change the line

```
If delshape.Type = msoAutoShape Then delshape.Delete
```

to

```
If delshape.Type = msoPicture Then delshape.Delete
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the link to learn more regarding the shape information!